# Client uses RestTemplate.getPostObject() to Server, but @RequestBody can't parse

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Springboot 2.2.2 + SpringCloud Hoxton SR1

It is just an order-payment demo.

Here is my code for the client to create an order to server:

```java
@Resource
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@GetMapping(value = "/consumer/payment/create")
public CommonResult<Payment> create(Payment payment){
  return restTemplate.postForObject(PAYMENT_URL + "/payment/create", payment, CommonResult.class);
}
```

Code for Server

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/payment/create")
public CommonResult create(@RequestBody Payment payment){
  int result = paymentService.create(payment);
  log.info("******result：" + result + "******" + payment + "******");
  if(result > 0){
     return new CommonResult(200, "insert success，ServerPort：" + serverPort, result);
   } else {
       return new CommonResult(444, "insert failed，ServerPort：" + serverPort, null);
   }
}
```

Then

I used postman send an address:

http://localhost/consumer/payment/create?serial=tom

The error for client is:

```
2020-05-29 19:42:15.546 ERROR 5348 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 : [{"timestamp":"2020-05-29T11:42:15.544+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMe... (6245 bytes)]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 : [{"timestamp":"2020-05-29T11:42:15.544+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMe... (6245 bytes)]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:133) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:421) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at edu.imu.springcloud.Controller.OrderController.create(OrderController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

The warning for the server is:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

I debugged the create method on the server-side. After sending the get request using postman, I found that the create method was not executed, or did not enter the function body, but when debugging the client, I found that he had returned the result.

When I removed `@RequestBody` it can work but the content for 'payment' is `null`.

It seems to me that `@RequestBody` rejected my request and returned an error message.

Here is my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 80

spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-order-service

 eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:7001/eureka/, http://localhost:7002/eureka/
```

And ApplicatonConfig

```java
    @Configuration
    public class ApplicationContextConfig {

        @Bean
        @LoadBalanced
        public RestTemplate getRestTemplete(){
            return new RestTemplate();
        }
    }
```

I do not know what happened pls help me...

Comment: For some reason, your request is sending `XML` instead of `JSON`. You can add a header to force it to be JSON. Can you show your configuration classes and properties?

Comment: ok，i have editen my question

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/consumer/payment/create")
    public CommonResult<Payment> create(Payment payment){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("id", payment.getId());
        jsonObject.put("serial", payment.getSerial());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject, headers);
        return restTemplate.postForObject(PAYMENT_URL + "/payment/create", entity, CommonResult.class);
    }
```